# minitoc: no rules and title

Tags: minitoc

Following this simple example below, minitoc rules and tiltle are hidden (even with `\mtcrule`.
However according to the minitoc documention, given the book document class, the default would displayed.

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openright
]{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\title{My title}
\author{You and me}

\dominitoc
\mtcrule

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc
\section{Motivation and Challenges}
\section{Hypothesis and Objectives}
\section{Contributions}
\section{Outline of the Dissertation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am missing something ?

Comment: You should read the `.log`. It mentions you're not executing `\tableofcontents` nor `\faketableofcontents`. Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `\dominitoc` behind `\begin{document}` (see Table 1.1–1.3 in [the `minitoc` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minitoc/minitoc.pdf)) and also use either `\tableofcontents` or `\faketableofcontents`. You do not need `\mtcrule`:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openright
]{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\title{My title}
\author{You and me}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents% or \faketableofcontents
%\mtcrule


\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc
\section{Motivation and Challenges}
\section{Hypothesis and Objectives}
\section{Contributions}
\section{Outline of the Dissertation}

\end{document}
```

[image]